# What is this type of slab called?

Tags: landscaping, paving

I am trying to build something like this
[image]

and I do not know what is the generic name for this type of slab. What is it called? I want to use it in the above mentioned design

[image]

Comment: The top is some kind of plastic formed edging.  The bottom is just some plank-style pavers or possibly even exterior tiles on a bed of gravel.

Comment: I doubt that the lower photo shows masonry or ceramic. It wouldn't withstand the load, being that thin. Must be plastic or fiber composite.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood that is just a decorative layout definitely not a slab.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the long, relatively thin stones (or cast imitation stones) are seen as the tops of walls (though in your first picture the walls may be unseen - in a freezing climate without walls under them the stones will shift every winter) and are called **coping** stones.

It is possible that in your second picture there is enough porus rock under them to serve as a "railbed" style foundation (there's another term for that which escapes me at the moment - rubble trench?) where well-drained coarse rocks prevent water from building up and freezing to the point of moving the stones on top. I also assume that the visible part of the stones is half or less of the stones overall thickness. Typical coping stones are 2-3 inches (50-75mm) in thickness.

It's also possible that both pictures are from non-freezing climates - perhaps you are as well. In freezing climates, one has to take steps to prevent annual movement from frost.

Comment: "steps to prevent annual movement from frost" You mean "steps to _minimize_ annual movement from frost", don't you? You can't really prevent it...